# creating variable-names through loop and adding extension

Tags: string, loops, variables, python-3.7

I'm new to Stack Overflow. I searched for tips on my problem but unfortunately i could not find the solution i was looking for. I think it is not a very hard problem but i don't see the syntax error and it's driving me crazy. so the code:

```py
MP = []
MP_ext = 2019
MP_num = 3

for x in range(0:MP_num):
  MP[x] = MP.append('MP%s_%s' %MP_ext %x)

print(MP)
```

alternatively i tried this:

```py
for x in range(0:MP_num):
  MP[x] = MP.append('MP' + str(MP_ext) + '_' + str(x))

print(MP)
```

What i try to get is the vector MP like this:

```py
[
  MP2019_1,
  MP2019_2,
  MP2019_3
]
```

Thanks in advance for any advices

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I hope this helps:

```py
MP = []
MP_ext = 2019
MP_num = 3

# range takes a single argument: an integer
# (it has optional arguments, see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp)
# it will return a range of values like this: range(3) = [0,1,2]
for x in range(MP_num):
  # string formatting using f-strings (Python 3.6+)
  # list.append is in-place - list is mutable, don't need to reassign it
  MP.append(f'MP{MP_ext}_{x+1}')

print(MP)
```